# Getting contents of main memory in java

Tags: java, memory

Its not problem specific but is it possible to get a copy of current memory state, as in just get whatever is there in the main memory. I mean is there any way we can get an image of RAM in java.

I am editing my question. So here is a screenshot of my Windows 7 Task Manager.

[image]

@peter I see that current memory usage is 3.27GB. So, can I get that whole thing in some read only memory and when I restart my OS, it resumes where I left off, as in whatever my last memory snapshot was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "main memory".

The JRE is designed

- to insulate your Java program from the OS around it, and vice versa.
- to insulate Java objects from the implementation details of other objects

With "ordinary" Java, you only get to see what classes and objects expose through public methods.

However, Java has its Reflection API, and with that, if your JRE is configured to allow it, you can break through these boundaries, and look deeper into the classes and objects within the JRE.

In Oracle HotSpot, you can start the JRE with the Java Servicability Agent -  http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html - this gives you access through an API to much more detail of the Java heap. But you're still restricted to memory claimed by the JRE process, and allocated to its heap.

One further possibility is to write a native library using JNI. There are C API calls that allow you to browse the OS address space. You need to be root (or the equivalent on your OS) to see other people's address space). You could write C code, and JNI to call it from Java.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for introducing me to JNI. I looked around and I think I will spend quite a long time on this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called a heap dump.

```
jmap -heap {pid}
```

dumps the heap to a file.

You can use `jvisualvm` to analyse the heap dump.